# how to fix ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE in ionic v1?

Tags: ssl, ionic-framework, amazon-ec2

We have a back-end API on AWS stage server not live.

But I got result failed while calling it.
[image]

I tried with cordova-plugin-whitelist and cordova-plugin-certificates but got the same result.
[image]

I am not sure that is an issue from backend config or ionic.

Comment: This points to a problem with the SSL certificate from the backend... it may be self-signed, or the wrong cert or a cert for the wrong domain name, or expired.